# How to create a shortcut in Start->Programs?

Tags: wix, shortcut

I have 3 Installers which install different products. I need to create shortcut for every product like this

```
Start->Programs->CompanyName->Product 1
                            ->Product 2
                            ->Product 3
```

How to do this?

Also, I'd like to remove CompanyName folder during uninstall if it is empty. i.e. one from un-installers must remove it if it is empty.

Comment: Wix Manual: [How To: Create a Shortcut on the Start Menu](http://wix.sourceforge.net/manual-wix3/create_start_menu_shortcut.htm).

Comment: Thanx, but the qstn is: how to remove CompanyName folder during uninstallation only by one of these uninstallers only if it is empty?

Comment: see the examples in the linked documentation, that's what the `RemoveFolder` element does.

Answer (score 0):

If you are having problems with orphaned shortcuts during the uninstall process of any of the three installers, you might be using the same GUID for the shortcut component or others.

This will cause the installer to disallow the uninstall of the component because it is in use for an other client(application installed) if you look at the logs you will find this message :
**Disallowing uninstallation of component: {GUID_ID}**

Following the instructions of the Wix Manual in the previous answer, you should not have any trouble creating the shortcuts you want and the behavior you want as well.